# What is the correct way to handle an error in awakeFromNib?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, model-view-controller

In my main application (`MyApp`) I programmatically create other windows by creating new instances of a window controller (`MyWindowController`). When the window controller is initialised, it loads a window and other views/objects from a nib file by calling `[self.window makeKeyWindow]`. In the `awakeFromNib` method on one of these objects (`MyModel`), there is some code that may fail (due to name resolution), and I would like to display an error to the user, and destroy the window controller, the window, and all related objects.

In summary:

1. Application creates new instance of `MyWindowController`.
2. `MyWindowController` loads a window and other views/objects from a nib file by calling `[self.window makeKeyWindow]`.
3. During `awakeFromNib` one of these objects (an instance of `MyModel`) encounters a failure (due to name resolution).
4. An error message is displayed to the user, and the instance of `MyWindowController`, `MyModel`, and all other related instances are destroyed.

How would I accomplish step 4 in the most Cocoa-esque way?

Just to clarify: I know how to present an error to the user using `NSError`. I am trying to find out if the recommended/correct way to handle an error in `awakeFromNib` is to display the error and release everything from within `awakeOnNib`, or if there is a better way to do it (that may require restructuring my app).

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but a window controller doesn't load anything from a nib until the `-window` message is sent for the first time (which in turn calls `-loadWindow`, which isn't called directly).

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks. I call [self.window makeKeyWindow] straight away. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2):

The most brutally Cocoa manner in which to present an error is to use `-[NSResponder presentError:]`.

If the object from which you issue this message inherits from `NSResponder`, you can use:

```
[self presentError:someError];
```

or if not, you could use this:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:someError];
```

or alternatively:

```
[NSApp presentError:someError];
```

There are also variants of `-presentError:` that let you present your errors as window-modal sheets instead of application-modal dialogs.

All of this assumes that you've somehow got an instance of `NSError` to pass as `someError`. I'm not familiar with your model object. When you say it "encounters a failure," does that mean some method on your model class provides this error object? Or does a method on some other object that takes your model object as an argument provide the error? In either case, your method providing the error object should follow a form like this:

```
- (BOOL)myMethodReturningAnErrorByReference:(NSError **)error
```

or

```
- (id)myMethodReturningAnErrorByReference:(NSError **)error
```

In the former example, the method returns `YES` or `NO`, and in the case of `NO`, an instance of `NSError` should be returned by reference, which you can then present. In the latter example, your method returns either a valid reference to an object, or it returns `nil`, and in the case of `nil`, again, an instance of `NSError` should be returned by reference, which you can then present.

Furthermore, you can conditionally present the error by examining its `code` and `domain` properties. It's also possible to override `-willPresentError:` on your `NSResponder` inheriting class where you can customize the content of the presentation.

Finally, [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html) in Apple's online documentation provides a wealth of background information. I completely glossed over the error-responder chain used in presenting errors, but it's covered there.

Good luck to you in your endeavors.

Comment: The method that has the error (I create the NSError) is `awakeFromNib`, which I can't really return an error from. I can easily present the error to the user, but am not sure how to get rid of all the objects (some of which may not be visible yet).

Comment: @DanielGibbs If you're instantiating your model objects from a nib or xib, they belong to that. Don't try to release them; they'll go away with your window controller when it's released.

Comment: Ok. I tried removing all references to the window controller but I must have missed some. Is this the correct way to handle an error in `awakeFromNib`?

Comment: @DanielGibbs You do have the advantage of me, since I don't know exactly what you're doing inside `-awakeFromNib`. But, if you're creating your own instances of `NSError` there, then you can present them from there just as I've described in the answer.

Comment: Sure, but what I'm trying to figure out is if this is the recommended/correct way to do this sort of thing in Cocoa, or if I should restructure my app and do it a different way.

Comment: @DanielGibbs The short answer is that it is, and has been since OS X 10.4, which was a long time ago. Apple has put into place, IMHO, a terrific mechanism for packaging errors and presenting them to the user. It's got thunder appeal, as the song goes. Let it be on your side.

Comment: I have updated the question to be more clear on what exactly I am asking.